# Ruby : Pass array in command line argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, command-line-arguments

I want to pass array in argument in such a way suppose process.rb is my script and the argument will be like:

i/p

```
process.rb server{1..4} 
process.rb prodserver{2..3} 
process.rb devserver3
```

The process.rb should accept all the inputs and parse it in such a way that when I print the variable which holds the arguments give me below result.

```
o/p
    puts arguments

    server1
    server2
    server3
    server4
    or
    prodserver2
    prodserver3
    or
    devserver3
```

I have a shell script which does the same:

```
for i in "$@"
do
echo $i
done

i/p
server{1..4} 
o/p
server1server2server3server4
```

I wanted to have the same logic in the ruby.
Since I am a new bie in ruby I am not able to find the same on google.
Please let me know how I can get this output or any article about the related to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to expand the range that comes in string form from your argument ARGV[0] ? My samples use a string to demonstrate it workd, replace the string by ARGV[0]

```
def expand_range arg
  string, range = arg.split("{") #split arg in string part and rangestring part
  if range #if a range is given
    # parse the rangestring to an range by splitting the string on .. 
    # and splash this array to both its elements, convert them to integer
    # and transform into a real range
    # and enumerate each number in the range
    Range.new(*range.split("..").map(&:to_i)).each do |val|
      #concatenate the string part with the number
      p "#{string}#{val}"
    end
  else #else just pass the string
    p string
  end
end

expand_range 'server{1..4}'
# "server1"
# "server2"
# "server3"
# "server4"

expand_range 'devserver3' 
#"devserver3"
```

Personally I would return an array and print that instead of printing in the method itself, that would be more multifunctional.

Comment: It is perfect man thanks a lot.
Also can you please give a little idea about whats going on in between line 2-4.

Comment: sure: i'll ad it to my answer

Comment: @peter I don't get it either, could you explain it?

Comment: The OP want to run `process.rb server{1..4}`, right? The shell expands this for you and passes 4 parameters to the ruby script.

Comment: Question clearly states that shell script with `for` loop does what OP wants (and it takes already expanded arguments from shell). But it seems OP wants Ruby script to parse arguments, not shell, without telling it clearly.

Comment: no, the shell does't expand the range, in the example the OP gives from the shell he uses a for loop do let the shell do that for him, in this case the script receives the range as a normal string. Either you use the shell or you use the script but not both

Comment: @peter Have you tested it? I even copied his "script" to test inputs, and my answer does exactly what his shell script which "does the same thing" he want to get, as OP says.

Comment: The shell *does* expand the range, try running `echo server{1..4}`

Comment: to be sure i tested your script, as expected i only got the string itself (I'm on windows, thatr makes the difference I guess, anyway my solution works in all OS)
process.rb server{1..3}
=>server{1..3}

Comment: @peter It says 'unix' in tags, not Windows, and from reading example I guessed it is in Bash shell, as sh doesn't expand `{x..y}` range. So still, you're wrong in that question was clear. And as Stefan said, try running simple `echo` with arguments. You can even test it under Cygwin's Bash.

Comment: you should ask OP to test, I don't use any form of Nix, so no Cygwin neither but I believe everyting is clear now, the question was clear to a Windows user, so lets close this discussion and go on to the next question..

Answer (score 4):

The list is expanded by the shell before it ever hits your script. In other words, both your shell script and your Ruby script *do not* receive a single argument `server{1..4}` but rather they receive *four* arguments `server1 server2 server3 server4`, *before* they even start interpreting the arguments themselves.

You can simply just iterate over those, there is no need to parse the `{1..4}` shell expansion syntax yourself because you will *never* see it! It is already parsed and expanded by the shell *before* the shell passes off the arguments to your script.

```
ruby -e 'p ARGV' -- server{1..4}
# ["server1", "server2", "server3", "server4"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!ruby

ARGV.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Basically `ARGV` holds all arguments passed to program, and `puts` prints string with new line added (the same as `echo` without `-n` flag in shell).

Comment: Sorry to say but its wrong. Let me explain you again what I am expecting. Suppose I have 12 servers names server1,2,3....12 
and I want to pass the server name in indexed parameter for e.x.

i/p 
server{1..5}
than I should get server1, server2, server3, server4, server5 as a value in a variable.
Consider another example.

I/P:
server{3..3}
Than I will get server3 only

I/P
server{1..2,5..9}
Than I will get server1, server2, server5, server6,server7 server8,server9.
I think these examples will help you to understand the problem

Comment: @A_01 So you pass range in `{}` which is **expanded** by default in **shell**, show example which takes advantage of this automatic expansion, and as I understand works for you, but obviously not for your new examples, but you want something else? Then yes, my answer is incorrect.

Comment: That's correct, invoking your script with `process.rb server{1..4}` will pass 4 parameters and set `ARGV` to `["server1", "server2", "server3", "server4"]`

Comment: My apologies. I got distracted yes @MBO its correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Command-line arguments in Ruby end up in `ARGV`. You can duplicate your shell script's functionality by iterating over that:

```
ARGV.each do |a|
    puts a
end
```

Comment: Thanks 4 reply. But unfortunetely your anser is incorrect.
If you read the question correctly you will understand what o/p I am expecting. sorry to say you answer incrorect

Comment: Oops, thanks. Fixed. That's what happens when you're forced to switch from Ruby to Python for a year. :)

Comment: @A_01: Yes, the question clearly says what output you are expecting and this answer produces exactly that output. What's incorrect about that?